# AccessDeniedException not caught by @ExceptionHandler

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have exception handler like this:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(BadCredentialsException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ApiError> handleBadCredentials(Exception e, HttpServletRequest request) {

        ApiError apiError = new ApiError(
                request.getRequestURI(),
                e.getMessage(),
                HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(),
                LocalDateTime.now()
        );

        return new ResponseEntity<>(apiError, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ApiError> handleMethodNotSupportedException(Exception e, HttpServletRequest request) {

        ApiError apiError = new ApiError(
                request.getRequestURI(),
                e.getMessage(),
                HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(),
                LocalDateTime.now()
        );

        return new ResponseEntity<>(apiError, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(AccessDeniedException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ApiError> handleAccessDeniedException(Exception e, HttpServletRequest request) {

        ApiError apiError = new ApiError(
                request.getRequestURI(),
                e.getMessage(),
                HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value(),
                LocalDateTime.now()
        );

        return new ResponseEntity<>(apiError, HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
    }
    @ExceptionHandler(EntityNotFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ApiError> handleEntityNotFound(Exception e,
                                                         HttpServletRequest request) {
        ApiError apiError = new ApiError(
                request.getRequestURI(),
                e.getMessage(),
                HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value(),
                LocalDateTime.now()
        );

        return new ResponseEntity<>(apiError, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ApiError> handleIllegalArgument(Exception e,
                                                          HttpServletRequest request) {

        ApiError apiError = new ApiError(
                request.getRequestURI(),
                e.getMessage(),
                HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(),
                LocalDateTime.now()
        );

        return new ResponseEntity<>(apiError, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

ApiError.class:

```
public record ApiError(
        String path,
        String message,
        int statusCode,
        LocalDateTime date
) {
}
```

I am trying to intercept exception thrown by `@PreAuthorize` method. Despite declared exception handler for it, it is not intercepted by `@ExceptionHandler`. I've tried to display logs about unsuccessful request.

Logs:

```
2023-08-03T15:05:56.895+02:00 DEBUG 22212 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured PATCH /api/v1/projects/3/volunteers/1
2023-08-03T15:05:56.897+02:00 DEBUG 22212 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] horizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor : Authorizing method invocation ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.example.demo.Controller.ProjectController.addVolunteerToProject(java.lang.Long,java.lang.Long,com.example.demo.Objects.CustomUserDetails); target is of class [com.example.demo.Controller.ProjectController]
2023-08-03T15:05:56.928+02:00 DEBUG 22212 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] horizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor : Failed to authorize ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.example.demo.Controller.ProjectController.addVolunteerToProject(java.lang.Long,java.lang.Long,com.example.demo.Objects.CustomUserDetails); target is of class [com.example.demo.Controller.ProjectController] with authorization manager org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.DeferringObservationAuthorizationManager@3ba2dc24 and decision ExpressionAuthorizationDecision [granted=false, expressionAttribute=hasAuthority('AUTHORITY_ADMIN')]
2023-08-03T15:05:56.930+02:00 DEBUG 22212 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl   : Responding with 403 status code
2023-08-03T15:05:56.932+02:00 DEBUG 22212 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing PATCH /error
2023-08-03T15:05:56.933+02:00 DEBUG 22212 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-08-03T15:05:56.933+02:00 DEBUG 22212 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
```

As we could see, some class called `AccessDeniedHandlerImpl` already handles this request, making `@ExceptionHandler` unable to do it. I have no such class in my project, nor my security class implements it or declares it.

Security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsCustomImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    private JwtFilter jwtFilter;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityfilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf((csrf) -> {
                    csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers(
                            AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/h2-console/**"));
                    csrf.disable();
                }
        );
        http.headers((headers) -> {
            headers.frameOptions((frameOption) -> frameOption.disable());
        });
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/h2-console/**"),
                                AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/api/v1/auth/**")).permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }

    public void configureAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    public void configureIgnores(WebSecurity web) {
        web
                .ignoring()
                .requestMatchers("/h2-console/**");
    }
}
```

Comment: Spring Security executes with a filter which aren't being handled/covered by the `HandlerExceptionResolver`s from Spring MVC. Spring Security has a default `AccessDeniedHandler` which handles this (which is why you don't need to configure one). You can write an `AccessDeniedHandler` which would delegate to the `HandlerExceptionResolver`.

Comment: I've tried to implement custom handler and delegate request to resolver. Like that: ```exceptionResolver.resolveException(request, response, null, accessDeniedException);``` but still I get no appropriate response. I also get message in log that authorization failed but exception is still not caught by appropriate handlers.

Comment: Additionally, when I ```@Autowired``` ```HandlerExceptionResolver```, I get two beans, one with the name ```handlerExceptionResolver``` and the other one with name ```errorAttributes```. I'm confused, I didn't declare such beans

Comment: Spring will automatically create those beans, you need the `handlerExceptionResolver` one as that is the one that will delegate to the `@ExceptionHandler` annotated one. Finally you will also need a `AuthenticationEntryPoint` which handles the `AuthenticationException` instances (and turns them into a response and error code). They are different components for different parts one is for Authentication (the `BadCredentialsException` the other for Authorization (the `AccessDeniedException`). You might want to handle the top level error instead of those specific ones.